# Collecting a list of all object keys that meet certain criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function `getActiveProp`:

```
const getActiveProp = obj => Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k].active);
```

But now, instead of finding the first item matching the criteria, I want to get an array of all of them.

I know I could simply do something like this, and wrap it in a function:

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var arr2 = [];
arr.forEach(k => arr2.push(k));
```

But I was just wondering if there was a one-line way to do it, creating the array within the `forEach` method itself, or using some similar array method to do it. Can that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in place of `Array#find`:

```js
let object = {
  inactiveProp1: { active: false },
  activeProp1: { active: true },
  activeProp2: { active: true }
}

const getActiveProps = o => Object.keys(o).filter(k => o[k].active)

console.log(getActiveProps(object))
```